# Modify template's front page to support lengthier subject titles and two additional text lines

Tags: titles, templates

I know that this is easy, but I can't figure out how to make it work with a 3 or 4 -line subject title. Any suggestion?

The template of the project I am working on is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5301947/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.zip).

EDIT: In additiona, how could I add the following two lines (and the appropriate space) just below my my name:

```
Supervised by
<name>
```

where, , preferably, should be in the form of link, exactly as my name.

EDIT 2: I added the following after line 222 in ".cls" file:

```
{{\supervisiontext} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
{\it {\@supervisor} \par}
\vspace*{15mm}
```

And the following in "thesis.tex" file:

```
\renewcommand{\supervisiontext}{supervised by}
\ifpdf
    \supervisor{\href{mailto:xxx@xxx.xx}{xxx xxx}}
\else
    \supervisor{xxx xxx}
\fi
```

But, unfortunately, it stills not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, I think you need to adjust the definition of `\maketitle` provided by `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls`. If you reduce the arguments to the `\vspace` commands you can create space for additional material on the first page. You can also see how your name is typeset and insert the name of your supervisor in the same way. However, note that many universities have very strict rules about the layout of PhD theses; you should check that you are not breaking any before you edit the class file.

Comment: Don't edit the original class file, make a copy with a new name like `myclass.cls` and change this one.

Comment: @Ian Please see EDIT 2 in my original post. Thank you.

Comment: @eualin --- You need to define `\@supervisor` and `\supervisor`. There are similar definitions on lines 184--192 of the class file. I think you just need to add `\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}`.